# How did the little girl die?

Tags: plot-explanation, vikings

In *Vikings*, We see Ragnar search for Helga and her daughter while he has Floki chained, awaiting a death sentence for killing the priest. He finds mother and daughter and has brought them food to survive winter starvation. When Flokis is freed in the night, Ragnar suspects Helga aided Floki, so he returns to Helga to ask her if she was involved in Flokis' escape. Ragnar finds Helga trying to dig the frozen earth to make a grave for her little girl.

Ragnar, always Paternal, emotionally digs the grave despite severe abdominal pain from his recent battle in France.  As he digs he asks Helga how the child died and if Floki is aware. She says,

> Does it matter? She has not told Floki.

Ragnar and Helga put the wrapped body of Flokis' daughter in the frozen ground and Helga clings to her king and friend Ragnar. Why wouldn't she tell Ragnar how the girl died?  Why did he accept a non-answer? What did the child die from?

Comment: Not really an answer, but from the in-story point of view - nobody really cared why. Kids were just dying. A woman in that region had on average 7 infants, of which about 2-3 were expected to live to adulthood